# Why do it get the value None when I use print(function())

Tags: python, function, nonetype

Trying to understand why this is happening.
When I put tall() inside print(), it prints tall() but ALSO a None value. Why is the value None given after it has already printed out tall()?

```
def tall():
    print('31337')
print(tall())
```

Result:

```
31337
None
```

Comment: Because tall() doesn't return anything.

Comment: In `print(2 + 2)`, `2 + 2` has a value. Which value do you think `tall()` has? Compare what you know about the expression `tall()` to other expressions, and try some things out in the REPL.

Comment: The return type of your function tall() is None. That's why it is printing the output like this.

Answer (score 0):

You must know that a function always return a value and in your case your function is not returning any value so the None value also.